# how to continue d3 chain within embedded switch?

Tags: d3.js

```
 .append(function(d,i) {
    switch (tabData.list[tabNo].type) {
       case 'actl':
          // return a div() chain .attr/.property/.on
         var v = document.createElement("div");
         var v1 = d3.select(v)
            .append("h3")
            .html("HFree");
          return v1;
          //return document.createElement("div");
          break;
       case 'fc':
          // return a div() chain .attr/.property/.on
          return document.createElement("div");
          break;
       case 't':
          // return a div().attr/.property/.on
          return document.createElement("div");
          break;
    }
 })
```

.append() takes either a string 'div or function that returns created element. How do I continue the chain within the switch as in // return a div() chain .attr/.property/.on? I have edited the first case statement to one of the things I tried that does not work in order to explain better.

Comment: First: .append add elments to your DOM.Second: Whats the point on switch? all of the return same value 'document.createElement("div")'. Just: .append("div")

Comment: ah I simplified the example code - each switch adds a specific chart based on type. The example code is functional. I want to embed a chain in each switch. I have to do all this with one pass, hence the switching complexity. This is of course about 2 yards of code before the .append()

Comment: Move common code into functions and call the functions.